# ¿Cómo agregar eventos a una tabla de Bootstrap-Table?

Tags: javascript, modal, eventos, bootstrap-5, bootstrap-table

Tengo una dificultad al agregar un evento a las imágenes que tengo dentro de una tabla para que ejecuten una función que mostrará una imagen modal al darle clic.

Tengo una tabla de productos de supermercado con varias columnas, con paginación y con barra de búsqueda hecha con [bootstrap 5](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/getting-started/introduction/) y [bootstrap-table](https://bootstrap-table.com/docs/getting-started/introduction/), en una de las columnas muestro una imagen miniatura de cada producto. Intento hacer que las imágenes sea imágenes modales para que el usuario pueda ampliarlas siguiendo el ejemplo de [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_modal_img), adaptándolo a mi aplicación.

El problema radica en que no logro agregar los *EventListener* desde JavaScript de una forma discreta (separando html y JavaScript).

Mi código html es el siguiente:

```
<div class="container">
<br/>
<div class="col-md-10 mx-auto" >

    <table class="table table-bordered table-hover text-center" 
       data-toggle="table" 
       data-pagination="true"
       data-page-size="5"
       data-search="true">
        <thead>
            <tr >
                <th data-width=300" >Nombre</th>
                <th data-width="150" >Cantidad</th>
                <th data-width="100" >Precio</th>
                <th  >Imagen</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <?php foreach($listaProductos as $producto){ ?>
            <tr>
                <td class="fs-5"> <?php echo $producto['nombre']; ?> </td>
                <td> <?php echo $producto['cantidad']; ?> </td>
                <td class="fw-bold" > $ <?php echo $producto['precio']; ?> </td>
                <td> 

                    <img class="myImg" id="<?php echo $producto['imagen']; ?>" src="./imagenes/<?php echo $producto['imagen']; ?>" style="width:105px;height:120spx;" >
                    
                </td>
            </tr>
            <?php } ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>

    <!-- The Modal -->
    <div id="myModal" class="modal">
        <span class="close">&times;</span>
        <img class="modal-content" id="img01">
        <div id="caption"></div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Como pueden ver, los elementos *img* que agrego con php dentro del la última columna de la tabla tendrán una *clase* en común y un *id* distinto cada uno.

En cuanto a mi código JavaScript con el que intento agregarles la función que hará todo acerca de la imagen modal, es el siguiente:

```
document.querySelectorAll(".myImg").forEach(el => {
  el.addEventListener("click", e => {
    const id = e.target.getAttribute("id");
    console.log("Se ha clickeado el id "+id);
    
    // Get the modal
    var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");

    // Get the image and insert it inside the modal - use its "alt" text as a caption

    var modalImg = document.getElementById("img01");
    var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");

    modal.style.display = "block";
    modalImg.src = "imagenes/"+id;

    // Get the <span> element that closes the modal
    var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

    // When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
    span.onclick = function() { 
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
  });
});
```

Y esto es lo que no me está funcionando. Ya verifiqué que el *document.querySelectorAll(".myImg")* esté obteniendo todas las *img* y sí lo hace. También estoy implementando el css correspondiente para que las imágenes tengan un grado de opacidad al pasar el cursor sobre ellas mediante la clase *myImg*, use está última implementación o no sigue sin funcionar. Tambien, como pueden ver, intento imprimir en consola del navegador para detectar la imagen seleccionada y nunca imprime nada.

Lo qué me funcionó fue colocar el evento y la función directamente en el html dentro de *img* como muestro aquí:

```
<img onclick="MostrarImg()" class="myImg" id="<?php echo $producto['imagen']; ?>" src="./imagenes/<?php echo $producto['imagen']; ?>" style="width:105px;height:120spx;" >
```

y la funcion *MostrarImg* de JavaScript queda de la siguiente manera, que como pueden ver, es practicamente lo mismo, salvo la forma en que obtengo el *id* del la imagen que originó el evento:

```
function MostrarImg(clicImg) {
    var eventoImg = clicImg || window.event;

    var id = eventoImg.target.getAttribute("id");

    // Get the modal
    var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");

    // Get the image and insert it inside the modal - use its "alt" text as a caption

    var modalImg = document.getElementById("img01");
    var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");

    modal.style.display = "block";
    modalImg.src = "imagenes/"+id;

    // Get the <span> element that closes the modal
    var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

    // When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
    span.onclick = function() { 
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

A pesar de qué este último ejemplo es el que me funcionó, no es lo qué quiero en cuanto a implementación ya que quiero que quede en una forma de JavaScript discreto.

Otra cosa qué me funcionó fue colocar una clase al elemento *table* con la cual obtenerla a partir de *document.querySelectorAll("clase")* y agregarle el *EventListener* a todo elemento que contenga, pero el problema es que cuando cliqueo en cualquier cosa que no sea una imagen, también se lanza el modal pero sin imagen lol.

Agradecería qué alguien me pueda ayudar con esto. No veo dónde esté radicando el error al agregar el evento que lance la imagen modal a cada imagen en mi primer ejemplo.

Comment: Tienes dos errores tipográficos: 1) Te falta una comilla aqui: `<th data-width=300" >Nombre</th>` ... tiene que ser asi: `<th data-width="300" >Nombre</th>`... y luego no cierras el `<div id="container">` al final del código mostrado (seguramente hay más código, lo digo por si acaso)... No se si tiene nada que ver con tu problema aun, pero de momento corrige eso

Comment: No entiendo esto: `<img class="myImg" id="<?php echo $producto['imagen']; ?>" src="./imagenes/<?php echo $producto['imagen']; ?>`... es decir, ¿le estas poniendo como id el nombre de la imagen?  Aunque html5 lo permite no se si es buena idea, la verdad, es tu decisión (espero que los productos nunca compartan imagenes).

Comment: Otro trozo de código que no has pegado bien, o tienes mal, es el de javascript que empieza por `document.querySelectorAll(`, pues no lo cierras adecuadamente. Te falta esto al final para cerrar esa funcion: `});`... sigo mirando

Comment: Bueno, parece que eso es todo... puedes ver tu un ejemplo de tu código corregido y funcionando aqui:  https://jsfiddle.net/p0b6tqoh/  (he tenido que retocar cosas, pero diria que mas o menos es lo que quieres)

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y pon en el título _cuál_ es el problema. Dado que tu planteamiento es extenso, es difícil entender de buenas a primeras el problema que estás teniendo. Lee [ask].

Comment: Gracias @masterguru !! Salvo el error en la comilla faltante, lo demás fue error de copiado y pegado. Tu ejemplo de mi código funcionando me ha ayudado mucho. he visto qué el error está en las bibliotecas de java script que estoy usando, parece que no son compatibles entre ellas o algo parecido, he quitado algunas que tengo y colocado la de tu ejemplo y sí funciona, aunque no en Chrome, sí es Firefox XD. En cuanto a tu comentario sobre el id de las img, me he asegurado que no se repitan, aunque estoy pensando si tomar otro enfoque que no sea su nombre.

Comment: Le daré una revisada @padaleiana, gracias.

Comment: Me alegra que todo te vaya mejor ahora. En cuanto al Chrome, si que funciona, pero al no haber imagen no lo parece, y es porque ni me habia fijado que el codigo del modal en si lo habias "reinventado" en lugar del que pone en el [manual del bootstrap 5](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/components/modal/#modal-components).  Te he dejado un nuevo código [aqui](https://jsfiddle.net/owLjhxfu/) que muestra una sintaxis más acorde con el manual y que en chrome tambien se aprecia mejor. Tambien he cambiado `close` en el javascript por `btn-close` que es la clase que se usa en bootstrap 5

Comment: @Bryan no olvides colocar en una respuesta lo que te ha sido útil, y luego [aceptarla](/help/accepted-answer) cuando transcurra el tiempo mínimo. Ten en cuenta que [el bot "Comunidad" se encarga de revivir las preguntas cada cierto tiempo](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1452).

Comment: @masterguru gracias. Ambos ejemplos funcionan bien en ambos navegadores. Vi que el problema surge por la incompatibilidad de algunas librerías de JacaScrip y Bootstrap. Y he aquí el problema, si incluyo JQuery, el eventlistener no funciona en ningún lado, si lo quito, el modal funciona perfecto. El problema es que la tabla con paginación y barra de búsqueda de Bootstrap-Table no funciona ya que este requiere JQuery. Agregaré lo qué me ha funcionado hasta el momento.

Comment: @Bryan: mmm... ¿no sera  un problema de orden de llamada de los scripts?  Es decir, primero hay que llamar al fichero de javascript de  jquery y luego al de  bootstrap.dentro del `<head></head>`

Comment: @masterguru ni al final del body ni en el head funciona y he intentado distintas combinaciones y tampoco. Y me extraña porque como menciono, si le agrego el eventlistener a todo lo que esté en el elemento table, accediendo a ese elemento desde una clase nueva, sí se agrega los eventos a las imágenes. De momento así lo tengo pero filtro las imágenes en el javascript ya que son las únicas que tienen id dentro de table. Te dejo lo más parecido a como lo tengo [aquí](https://jsfiddle.net/ur2L76ct/) (incluso las librerías), si cambias "clickk" por "myImg" en el JS, ya no funciona.

Comment: @Bryan: Uf, eso ya es algo muy específico de bootstrap-table, no me di cuenta hasta ahora.  A ver, mirate este ejemplo https://live.bootstrap-table.com/example/welcome.html y fíjate en como ellos capturan los clicks a las papeleras y los corazones, y extrapola su método para adaptarlo a tu caso.  Seguramente tendras que cambiar varias cosas para conseguirlo dentro del bootstrap-table.

Comment: Bueno, @masterguru , por fin resuelto. Bootstrat-Table tiene su propia forma de manejar los eventos, gracias al último link y a [este](https://live.bootstrap-table.com/example/column-options/events.html) un poco más simple pude implementarlo. [Aquí](https://jsfiddle.net/mz2as0fy/) el ejemplo completo. Aunque no me deja del todo complacido ya que mi objetivo era usar JavaScript discreto, y la forma en que se manejan los eventos aquí, hay que especificar los métodos en el html XD.

Comment: @Bryan: Me alegro por ti!  Ya veo que has tenido que usar cosas del bootstrap-table en el javascript para arreglarlo, como ya intuia... Supongo que eso te impide pasar a bootstrap 5, pero bueno, te ha quedado bonito :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El objetivo de mi duda era saber cómo agregar un evento clic a una columna de imágenes en una [bootstrap-table](https://bootstrap-table.com/docs/getting-started/introduction/) para que se mostrara un modal con la imagen cliqueada a través de JavaScript discreto y, gracias a los comentarios, me di cuenta que bootstrap-table tiene su propia manera de manejar los eventos en sus tablas, pero, creo yo, no es una forma total de JavaScript discreto. Así que he encontrado básicamente tres maneras de lograr la funcionalidad que quiero y solo una es JS discreto.

**1.** Especificar el método a utilizar con el atributo *onclick* en cada elemento *img* dentro de la tabla:

```js
function MostrarImg(clickImg) {

    var eventoImg = clickImg || window.event;
    var imagen = eventoImg.target.getAttribute("src");
    console.log("Se ha clickeado la imagen: "+imagen);

    // Get the modal
    var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");

    // Get the image and insert it inside the modal - use its "alt" text as a caption

    var modalImg = document.getElementById("img01");
    var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");

    modal.style.display = "block";
    modalImg.src = imagen;

    // Get the <span> element that closes the modal
    var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];
    //var span = document.getElementsByClassName("btn-close")[0];

    // When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
    span.onclick = function() {
      modal.style.display = "none";
    }

 }
```

```css
body {font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;}

.myImg {
  border-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.myImg:hover {opacity: 0.7;}

/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
  display: none; /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
  padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%; /* Full width */
  height: 100%; /* Full height */
  overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
  background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.9); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content (image) */
.modal-content {
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  width: 80%;
  max-width: 700px;
}

/* Caption of Modal Image */
#caption {
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  width: 80%;
  max-width: 700px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #ccc;
  padding: 10px 0;
  height: 150px;
}

/* Add Animation */
.modal-content, #caption {  
  -webkit-animation-name: zoom;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.6s;
  animation-name: zoom;
  animation-duration: 0.6s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes zoom {
  from {-webkit-transform:scale(0)} 
  to {-webkit-transform:scale(1)}
}

@keyframes zoom {
  from {transform:scale(0)} 
  to {transform:scale(1)}
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  right: 35px;
  color: #f1f1f1;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: bold;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: #bbb;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

/* 100% Image Width on Smaller Screens */
@media only screen and (max-width: 700px){
  .modal-content {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>

<!-- Bootstrap -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-zCbKRCUGaJDkqS1kPbPd7TveP5iyJE0EjAuZQTgFLD2ylzuqKfdKlfG/eSrtxUkn" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Bootstrap-Table -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.3/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-UHRtZLI+pbxtHCWp1t77Bi1L4ZtiqrqD80Kn4Z8NTSRyMA2Fd33n5dQ8lWUE00s/" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-table@1.19.1/dist/bootstrap-table.min.css">


<!-- Bootstrap -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.5.1/dist/jquery.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-fQybjgWLrvvRgtW6bFlB7jaZrFsaBXjsOMm/tB9LTS58ONXgqbR9W8oWht/amnpF" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<!-- Bootstrap-Table -->
<script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-table@1.19.1/dist/bootstrap-table.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-table@1.19.1/dist/locale/bootstrap-table-es-MX.js"></script>



</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
<br/>
<div class="col-md-10 mx-auto" >

    <table class="table table-bordered table-hover text-center" 
       data-toggle="table" 
       data-pagination="true"
       data-page-size="5"
       data-search="true">
        <thead>
            <tr >
                <th data-field="Nombre" data-width="300" >Nombre</th>
                <th data-field="Cantidad" data-width="150" >Cantidad</th>
                <th data-field="Precio" data-width="100" >Precio</th>
                <th data-field="Imagen" >Imagen</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <?php foreach($listaProductos as $producto){ ?>
            <tr>
                <td class="fs-5"> Nombre producto </td>
                <td> 10 </td>
                <td class="fw-bold" > $ 1000 </td>
                <td> 
                    
                    <img onclick="MostrarImg()" class="myImg" src="https://i.blogs.es/0142c8/beef-tongue-tacos-taquitos-de-lengua-fp/650_1200.jpg" style="width:105px;height:120spx;" >
                    
                </td>
            </tr>
            <?php } ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>

    <!-- The Modal -->
    <div id="myModal" class="modal">
        <span class="close">&times;</span>
        <img class="modal-content" id="img01">
        <div id="caption"></div>
    </div>

</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**2.** Implementar la manera en que Bootstrat-Table maneja los eventos agregando el nombre del método a utilizar con el atributo *data-events* en el elmento *th* de la columna de la tabla:

```js
window.operateEvents = {
  'click .myImg': function (e) {
    const imagen = e.target.getAttribute("src");
    console.log("Se ha clickeado la imagen: "+imagen);

    // Get the modal
    var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");

    // Get the image and insert it inside the modal - use its "alt" text as a caption

    var modalImg = document.getElementById("img01");
    var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");

    modal.style.display = "block";
    modalImg.src = imagen;

    // Get the <span> element that closes the modal
    var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];
    //var span = document.getElementsByClassName("btn-close")[0];

    // When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
    span.onclick = function() {
      modal.style.display = "none";
    }

  }
}
```

```css
body {font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;}

.myImg {
  border-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.myImg:hover {opacity: 0.7;}

/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
  display: none; /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
  padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%; /* Full width */
  height: 100%; /* Full height */
  overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
  background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.9); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content (image) */
.modal-content {
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  width: 80%;
  max-width: 700px;
}

/* Caption of Modal Image */
#caption {
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  width: 80%;
  max-width: 700px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #ccc;
  padding: 10px 0;
  height: 150px;
}

/* Add Animation */
.modal-content, #caption {  
  -webkit-animation-name: zoom;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.6s;
  animation-name: zoom;
  animation-duration: 0.6s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes zoom {
  from {-webkit-transform:scale(0)} 
  to {-webkit-transform:scale(1)}
}

@keyframes zoom {
  from {transform:scale(0)} 
  to {transform:scale(1)}
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  right: 35px;
  color: #f1f1f1;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: bold;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: #bbb;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

/* 100% Image Width on Smaller Screens */
@media only screen and (max-width: 700px){
  .modal-content {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>

<!-- Bootstrap -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-zCbKRCUGaJDkqS1kPbPd7TveP5iyJE0EjAuZQTgFLD2ylzuqKfdKlfG/eSrtxUkn" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Bootstrap-Table -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.3/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-UHRtZLI+pbxtHCWp1t77Bi1L4ZtiqrqD80Kn4Z8NTSRyMA2Fd33n5dQ8lWUE00s/" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-table@1.19.1/dist/bootstrap-table.min.css">


<!-- Bootstrap -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.5.1/dist/jquery.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-fQybjgWLrvvRgtW6bFlB7jaZrFsaBXjsOMm/tB9LTS58ONXgqbR9W8oWht/amnpF" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<!-- Bootstrap-Table -->
<script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-table@1.19.1/dist/bootstrap-table.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-table@1.19.1/dist/locale/bootstrap-table-es-MX.js"></script>



</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
<br/>
<div class="col-md-10 mx-auto" >

    <table class="table table-bordered table-hover text-center" 
       data-toggle="table" 
       data-pagination="true"
       data-page-size="5"
       data-search="true">
        <thead>
            <tr >
                <th data-field="Nombre" data-width="300" >Nombre</th>
                <th data-field="Cantidad" data-width="150" >Cantidad</th>
                <th data-field="Precio" data-width="100" >Precio</th>
                <th data-field="Imagen" data-events="operateEvents" >Imagen</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <?php foreach($listaProductos as $producto){ ?>
            <tr>
                <td class="fs-5"> Nombre producto </td>
                <td> 10 </td>
                <td class="fw-bold" > $ 1000 </td>
                <td> 
                    
                    <img class="myImg" src="https://i.blogs.es/0142c8/beef-tongue-tacos-taquitos-de-lengua-fp/650_1200.jpg" style="width:105px;height:120spx;" >
                    
                </td>
            </tr>
            <?php } ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>

    <!-- The Modal -->
    <div id="myModal" class="modal">
        <span class="close">&times;</span>
        <img class="modal-content" id="img01">
        <div id="caption"></div>
    </div>

</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**3.** Esta tercer forma es la que cumple con la implementación de JS discreto, aunque haciendo más manipulaciones de las que se deberían y consiste en, mediante JS, obtener el elemento *table* a partir de su clase y agregarle los eventos *click* a todo elemento que se encuentre dentro de la tabla mediante el método *addEventListener*, al mismo tiempo que se especifica el método a llamar en el evento y en este filtrar los elementos *img* mediante su id, ya que son los únicos elementos que tienen id dentro de la tabla:

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".clickk").forEach(el => {
  el.addEventListener("click", e => {
    
    const id = e.target.getAttribute("id");
    console.log("Se ha clickeado el id; " + id);

    if( id != null){

      // Get the modal
      var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");

      // Get the image and insert it inside the modal - use its "alt" text as a caption

      var modalImg = document.getElementById("img01");
      var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");

      modal.style.display = "block";
      modalImg.src = id;

      // Get the <span> element that closes the modal
      var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];
      //var span = document.getElementsByClassName("btn-close")[0];

      // When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
      span.onclick = function() {
        modal.style.display = "none";
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```css
body {font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;}

.myImg {
  border-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.myImg:hover {opacity: 0.7;}

/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
  display: none; /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
  padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%; /* Full width */
  height: 100%; /* Full height */
  overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
  background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.9); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content (image) */
.modal-content {
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  width: 80%;
  max-width: 700px;
}

/* Caption of Modal Image */
#caption {
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  width: 80%;
  max-width: 700px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #ccc;
  padding: 10px 0;
  height: 150px;
}

/* Add Animation */
.modal-content, #caption {  
  -webkit-animation-name: zoom;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.6s;
  animation-name: zoom;
  animation-duration: 0.6s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes zoom {
  from {-webkit-transform:scale(0)} 
  to {-webkit-transform:scale(1)}
}

@keyframes zoom {
  from {transform:scale(0)} 
  to {transform:scale(1)}
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  right: 35px;
  color: #f1f1f1;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: bold;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: #bbb;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

/* 100% Image Width on Smaller Screens */
@media only screen and (max-width: 700px){
  .modal-content {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>

<!-- Bootstrap -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-zCbKRCUGaJDkqS1kPbPd7TveP5iyJE0EjAuZQTgFLD2ylzuqKfdKlfG/eSrtxUkn" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Bootstrap-Table -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.3/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-UHRtZLI+pbxtHCWp1t77Bi1L4ZtiqrqD80Kn4Z8NTSRyMA2Fd33n5dQ8lWUE00s/" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-table@1.19.1/dist/bootstrap-table.min.css">


<!-- Bootstrap -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.5.1/dist/jquery.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-fQybjgWLrvvRgtW6bFlB7jaZrFsaBXjsOMm/tB9LTS58ONXgqbR9W8oWht/amnpF" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<!-- Bootstrap-Table -->
<script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-table@1.19.1/dist/bootstrap-table.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-table@1.19.1/dist/locale/bootstrap-table-es-MX.js"></script>



</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
<br/>
<div class="col-md-10 mx-auto" >

    <table class="table table-bordered table-hover text-center clickk" 
       data-toggle="table" 
       data-pagination="true"
       data-page-size="5"
       data-search="true">
        <thead>
            <tr >
                <th data-field="Nombre" data-width="300" >Nombre</th>
                <th data-field="Cantidad" data-width="150" >Cantidad</th>
                <th data-field="Precio" data-width="100" >Precio</th>
                <th data-field="Imagen" >Imagen</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <?php foreach($listaProductos as $producto){ ?>
            <tr>
                <td class="fs-5"> Nombre producto </td>
                <td> 10 </td>
                <td class="fw-bold" > $ 1000 </td>
                <td> 
                    
                    <img class="myImg" id="https://i.blogs.es/0142c8/beef-tongue-tacos-taquitos-de-lengua-fp/650_1200.jpg" src="https://i.blogs.es/0142c8/beef-tongue-tacos-taquitos-de-lengua-fp/650_1200.jpg" style="width:105px;height:120spx;" >
                    
                </td>
            </tr>
            <?php } ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>

    <!-- The Modal -->
    <div id="myModal" class="modal">
        <span class="close">&times;</span>
        <img class="modal-content" id="img01">
        <div id="caption"></div>
    </div>

</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

En este caso lo ideal sería solo agregar el evento a los elementos *img* y no a todo lo que esté dentro de la tabla, pero he aquí lo que tarde en darme cuenta, que bootstrap-table no lo permite directamente.